# Calculadora en javascript, resta en vez de sumar

Tags: javascript

Es una simple calculadora, solo con javascript. Sumar lo hace sin problema, pero cuando quiero restar, suma.

```js
var eleccion = prompt("Qué operación querés realizar? Las opciones son: Suma, Resta, Multiplicacion y Division")
var primer = prompt("Primer número?")
var segundo = prompt("Segundo número?")

if (eleccion == "Suma" || "suma") {
  document.write("El resultado es " + (Number(primer) + Number(segundo)))
} else if (eleccion == "Resta" || "resta") {
  document.write("El resultado es " + (Number(primer) - Number(segundo)))
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Tienes un problema con tus condiciones.  La forma correcta es asi:

```js
var eleccion = prompt("Qué operación querés realizar? Las opciones son: Suma, Resta, Multiplicacion y Division")
var primer = prompt("Primer número?")
var segundo = prompt("Segundo número?")

    if (eleccion == "Suma" || eleccion == "suma"){  
        document.write("El resultado es " + (Number(primer) + Number(segundo)))}
    else if (eleccion == "Resta" || eleccion == "resta"){ 
        document.write("El resultado es " + (Number(primer) - Number(segundo)))}
```

Comment: totalmente cierto, excelente respuesta

Answer (score 0):

La primera evaluación da como cierta (true) siempre

```
if (eleccion == "Suma" || "suma"){
```

si `eleccion` es igual a `"resta"` la primera parte :

```
if (eleccion == "Suma"
```

dará falso (false)

sin embargo la segunda parte

```
 "suma"){
```

va a dar cierto (true), esto junto sería:

```
if (false || true){
```

si falso o cierto da cierto